# Why can't I access my mac localhost ip in Parallels WIndows?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, cross-browser, localhost, parallels

I have my server running on my mac but I can't access it from windows.

I have followed the many posts about getting and using your local ip but none of them are working, all return 404, Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 4 you need to use 0.0.0.0 when starting the server, e.g.

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Then you can access the server using your local router ip address, e.g.

```
http://192.168.128.72:3000 (3000 is the ruby on rails port#)
```